# Speeding up an ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, database, data-warehouse

I am developing an ASP.NET web application.  The web application searches for people across about thirty different database (it is a law enforcement app).  For example, a police office searches for Fred Smith DOB 01/01/1950 (not a real person) and it returns any hits from all the databases.

For the majority of searches; the speed is acceptable i.e. if the average person has five hits then the average time to load the page is five seconds.  However, some searches have hundreds and sometimes thousands of hits.  I saw one search which took 25 minutes, which is obviously not acceptable.

Longer term a data warehouse will probably be created to ensure all the data is in one database.  However, what is the best strategy for speeding up searches in this scenario? I thought of caching but the same person is rarely searched for twice in a small amount of time.  Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Show some more of how you are implementing your searches/ Queries?

Answer (score 1):

You have insufficient details (what databases, whats the frontend language, how are you querying, is there indexing etc.)

but here are some preliminary suggestions.. (in the increasing order of effort, probably)

1. heavily index all the databases for the key columns and do your searches.
2. multi threading - spawn 30 threads (1 per database) and do the search. start displaying the results as the threads come back.
3. have a backend job to consolidate all data from 30 databases into a single denormalized table which is fully indexed. query that table.
4. setup #3 with mostly a SOLR/LUCERNE like indexing engine, for even faster querying.
5. use big data etc.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question, if you're db searches are taking too long, it's because the columns you are searching are not indexed or other db related issue. Showing them 'faster' with asp.net is the least of your problems.

Show us some code and it's easier to help out.